# find index of certain value in 3 dimension array in parallel way

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, pytorch

I made a `zero_mask2` function (copied below) in the middle of my pytorch file. However, it is too slow. So, I'm looking for a better way.

First, Let me explain the gist of the function below.

### Input

- `all_idx_before'` (dimension of `[batch_size, number of points, 20]`): batch_size is a well-known definition of mini batch in deep learning society. In every batch, there are many points like *1024*. And, in every point, a point has *20* values.
- `idx` (dimension of `[batch_size, number of points, 5]`): batch and number of points are same as before. But, in this case, a point has only *5* values.
- `p`: just an any number, for example, *7*.

### Toy example

Lets say, a point in `all_idx_before` has `(9, 10, 11, 12, 6, 7, 8, 14, 2, 3, 4, 5, 18, 19, 15, 16, 17, 13, 1, 20)`.

And a point in `idx` has `(10, 6, 2, 4, 18)`.

In this setting, I want to find the index of each value in `idx`. For example, `(10)` in `idx` is second element in `all_idx_before`, `(6)` in `idx` is fifth element in `all_idx_before`...

So, potential output of this point would be like `(1, 5, 8, 10, 12)`, `('second' becomes '1' because of number system in python.)`.

I do this logic in every batch and every point. So, I used for iteration. But this is too slow. Is there any way of doing this in parallel? I use NumPy format. But I can use tensor if it is better.

```
def zero_mask2(idx, all_idx_before, p):

size_batch = len(idx)
size_points = len(idx[0])
size_neighbor = len(idx[0][0])

mask = torch.empty(size_batch, size_points, size_neighbor)

for i in range(size_batch):
 for j in range(size_points):
  for l in range(size_neighbor):
   mask[i][j][l] = np.where(all_idx_before[i][j] == idx[i][j][l])[0][0] 

mask_t = mask <= p # smaller than p or same : true , bigger than p : false
return mask_t
```

Comment: are you guaranteed that each value in `idx` will be found _exactly_ once in `all_idx_before`?

Comment: yes! That is guaranteed and one and only.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare and use `argmax`:

```py
tmp = all_idx_before[..., None, :] == idx[..., None]  # compare along additional last dimension
mask = torch.argmax(tmp, dim=-1)
```

Comment: oh! thanks for the answer. I will try this and let you know.